# Launch Images not displaying after updating to Xcode 8.2.1

Tags: ios, xcode, launchimage

I downloaded Xcode 8.2.1 as I had updated my iphone to the latest version. I ran xcode and updated the current app I'm working on to the project recommended settings upon first opening of my project (This pops up after new version of xcode). After this I tried to run the project on my device (iPhone 6) and it simply loads an enlarged app icon instead of the iphone 6 size launch screen which I have in the Images.xcassets folder. Annoyingly I tested the app on the simulator (iphone 6, 10.2) and it works completely as it had been doing prior to xcode 8.2.1.

I'm at a complete loss as to what could be the problem: ive tried everything from restarting xcode, cleaning project, deleting and re-adding launch images, and made sure the launch screen entry was empty as I don't use them (removed the option from the plist as well).

Everytime I run the app on my own device, it crashes and is looking for a completely different storyboard (I use multiple storyboards for different screen sizes, which is a lot of work but works for me) and thus its telling me that there isn't a launch screen for the iPhone 6 screen size it has detected. But obviously there is as it works on the simulator.

Anybody have any reasons as to why this might be? I'm thinking it could be a bug on behalf of xcode 8.2.1, a lot of other users seem to be having odd problems as well with this version. For further clarity, I opened up another project but didnt update it to the recommended project settings that xcode displayed again, I ran the app on my device and hey presto! It worked with no issues.

Is there any way of reversing the update to the recommended project settings?

Comment: it will be working by it self after some time keep patients and try it another day

Answer (score 1):

Here also Same Issue, i upgraded to 8.3:

Ans: remove "Launch Screen Interface file base name" from plist. it will work.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Solved: The solution was simple and I wasted 5 hours on it. All I had to do was (1) remove the launch images from the xcassets folder, (2) rename launch images without .png extension and (3) I simply added them back into the Images.xcassets folder and ran the app again, this time it worked and showed the launch image correctly.

This might save someone hours of agony as I didn't think Xcode would be funny with a file extension such as .png